# I am trying to find a way to use IN() with LIKE() for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, case

I want to avoid doing nested `CASE THEN ELSE` statements.  I want to use `IN()`, but I do not know if I can use it inconjunction with `LIKE()`.  This would eliminate the need for deep nested case statements, and ease of added/removing/modifying criteria.

This is what I want:

```html
CASE
WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE 'Kel%')
THEN 2
ELSE CASE
    WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE 'RMA%')
    THEN 3
    ELSE CASE
        WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE IN('DC%', 'BT%', 'HF%'))
        THEN 5
        ELSE NULL
        END
     END
END AS OrderType
```

This is what I have:

```html
CASE
WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE 'Kel%')
THEN 2
ELSE CASE
    WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE 'RMA%')
    THEN 3
    ELSE CASE
        WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE 'DC%')
        THEN 5
        ELSE CASE WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE'BT%')
        THEN 5
        ELSE CASE WHEN(dbo.OrderDetail.OrderNumber LIKE 'HF%')
        THEN 5
        ELSE 

NULL
        END END END
     END
END AS OrderType
```

Comment: put the patterns to match and the Ordertypes and priority of match rule into a three column table, then you can query top 1 from that table that matches the pattern. You can use a table valued constructor instead of a permanent table also potentially

Comment: You don't need to nest them. `case when x = 1 then 'First' when x = 2 then 'Second' when x = 3 then 'Third' else end`. Use `or` to combine multiple conditions into a single `when`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you alias the table you can write this pretty compactly:

```
FROM dbo.OrderDetail as od
...
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'Kel%' THEN 2
        WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'RMA%' THEN 3
        WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'DC%'  THEN 5
        WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'BT%'  THEN 5
        WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'HF%'  THEN 5
    END AS OrderType
```

The cases resulting in the same value could be combined although I think there's hardly a reason to do so:

```
CASE
    WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'Kel%' THEN 2
    WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'RMA%' THEN 3
    WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'DC%'
      OR od.OrderNumber LIKE 'BT%'
      OR od.OrderNumber LIKE 'HF%'  THEN 5
END AS OrderType
```

Since you are dealing with the two leftmost characters you've got another alternative:

```
CASE 
    WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'Kel%' THEN 2
    WHEN od.OrderNumber LIKE 'RMA%' THEN 3
    WHEN LEFT(od.OrderNumber, 2) IN ('DC', 'BT', 'HF') THEN 5
END AS OrderType
```